# How do i delete a unknown account on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I tried deleting my last microsoft account because it had an email I no longer had access to. I now have a new 'main' account on my windows 10 PC. But somehow the old account still exists and takes up a lot of space from my disk. I can't see the files of the old account in my explorer, so I can't delete them but they do take up disk space. As you can see in the pictures below, it says that nearly all 250 GB of my disk are used according to the explorer. But if I check how much actual disk space should be used with WinDirStat it only says I have files that are 91.4GB on my hard drive. Any tips would be welcome.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You say that you are using WinDirStat. You can use WinDirStat to remove the directories which take too much space. In case this does not work, you can launch WinDirStat as administrator: as an administrator you have access to all files on your computer (right-click and mention "Als Administrator uitvoeren").

Comment: I can't believe I forgot trying it as administrator :'D. I can indeed see all the files now and delete them. Thank you!